# Is it possible to kebab case arguments in function prototypes?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, naming-conventions

Is it possible to kebab-case API arguments in C# WebApi?

C# sees everything after the first dash in the arg name (see code below) as wrong :)

Instead of:

```cs
public someFunction (string myString) {...}
```

Kebab-case args like this:

```cs
public someFunction (string my-string) {...}
```

Comment: The hyphen is an operator in C#. Something like `my-string` would normally mean "subtract `string` from `my`" (of course, since `string` is a reserved word, it doesn't even mean that)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is for a Web API action method and you're sending arguments as query-string parameters in a `GET` action, you can use the `[FromUri]` attribute for this, by specifying the expected name of the incoming query string parameter you want to bind to:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("test")]
public string Get([FromUri(Name = "my-argument")] string myArgument)
{
   return $"Argument was {myArgument}";
}
```

[image]